# Redirect only category pages with htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What is the best way to URL masking or redirect from:

```
http://www.domain.com/category/XXXX
```

TO:

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/category/XXXX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(category/.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seems to work.

htaccess:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bakingforlife\.tv$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(category/.*)$ http://coffee.bakingforlife.tv/$1 [R=301,NC,L]


for example here:
http://www.bakingforlife.tv/category/salty-pastries/

Comment: Is `/category` is real directory?

Comment: No, this is WordPress permalink

Comment: ok in that case move rule as **very first rule** (just below `RewriteEngine On` line) in root .htaccess